# Can't convert PFFile to UIImage using getDataInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I have an `updateCell` function which I call within a tableView function.

I'm trying to update the cell and convert the PFFile to a UIImage but I keep getting an error `Cannot convert value of type '(NSData?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFDataResultBlock?'`

Confused as I got this from the Parse docs and I can't for the life of my find a solution or where I'm going wrong. Here's my updateUI Function.

```
func updateUI(venue: Venue) {
        venueLabel.text = venue.name
        let venueImageFile = venue.image

        venueImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the Venue class

```
class Venue {

    private var _name: String!
    private var _location: String!
    private var _image: PFFile!

    var name: String {
        return _name
    }

    var location: String {
        return _location
    }

    var image: PFFile {
        return _image
    }

    init(name: String, location: String, image: PFFile) {
        self._name = name
        self._location = location
        self._image = image
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. At a point now where I don't know where to turn.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I couldn't find a solution using the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` so I ended up installing Parse UI which explains it perfectly...

> **PFImageView**
>
> Many apps need to display images stored in the Parse Cloud as PFFiles.
>   However, to load remote images with the built-in UIImageView involves
>   writing many lines of boilerplate code. PFImageView simplifies this
>   task by abstracting away these parts.

Once I imported this into my swift file, all I had to do was this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var venueImage: PFImageView! // Make sure it's this class in the storyboard. It's default would be UIImageView.

func updateUI(venue: Venue) {
    venueLabel.text = venue.name

    venueImage.file = venue.image
    venueImage.loadInBackground()
}
```

:)